# Matlab 2015a/2015b reading .off file using fscanf issue

Tags: matlab

I am a new user to Ubuntu. I have installed 14.04. I am using Matlab 2015a and trying to read .off file using fscanf but fscanf is returning empty matrix. I have compiled the same code on Windows and it has worked fine. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: That's intriguing. Can you provide your MATLAB code and `.off` file so that I can try to figure out what's happening?